# How to detect lines - OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, line, detection

I'm new to OpenCV and trying to do detect lines in a drawing in a format the same as contours are detected. For example, the following image needs to be processed:
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i6dS.png)

So far I have been able to detect the contours as follows:
[Detected contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DmTs.png)

What I'd like to do is detect the actual line and not the inner and outer contour but still have the result in the form of a list. Is this possible? If so, I'd like to apply this to pictures with more than one line such as:
[multiline drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzy8T.png)

All drawings will only consist of lines and no solid 'blocks'

Thanks very much!

Comment: I find this question useful because, among all the questions that seem to want this, this one is written well and contains no fluff or distractions. I *am* a little disappointed that hough lines seems to be the only answer so far. hough lines don't handle curves

Answer (score 0):

```
img = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, threshold=0)
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (51, 250, 250), 2)
cv2.imshow(img)
```